# Why did Nebula make this counterintuitive and nearly disastrous decision?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, on Morag in 2014 after retrieving the Power Stone, at the instant she is meant to beam herself back to present-day Avengers' headquarters, Nebula is linked to the 2014 version of herself and realizes with horror that Thanos now knows of their Time Heist plans. However, rather than sending herself back to the Avengers in 2019, she runs to her spaceship and attempts to send a warning by radio. She is captured by Thanos, who then uses her knowledge, part of her head plate, and her Pym particles to engineer his final battle.

Why did she try to radio rather than just returning and delivering her message in person?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why did she try to radio rather than just returning and delivering her message in person?

She's trying to warn her teammates who are in **2014**, War Machine, Black Widow and Hawkeye, so they can be aware and take the necessary precautions.

They are the ones trying to retrieve Infinity Stones at that point in time and so are at risk.

There would be no point in returning to the present to warn anyone since there is nothing they could do about it.

Comment: War Machine had already gone back to the “present”. She’s trying to warn Clint and Nat on Vormir only.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. In the heat of the moment she didn't realize that she was at risk as much as 2014 Black Widow and Hawkeye were, or she heroically put herself at risk to help them. It's hard to imagine what she thought the two of them might have *done* about it, had they known, but that's another question..

Comment: @MichaelStern: Generally speaking, Nebula doesn't really doubt her abilities (it's her self-worth and Thanos' approval that she doubts). She generally doesn't seem to think she's incapable of something, so it makes sense for her to do something on the assumption that she can accomplish it.